# looking to figure out a way to get dropdown to work in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

trying to get a dropdown to work above the menu on my site http://dev1.bsgcraft.com/

i want them top right like in https://bsghandcraft.com/

but when i put the menu on the top menu, it wont let me make it a drop down. is this limitations of the theme that i cant get around or is there some custom css way to do it like i wanted?

from what i can see  the ' hop analysis' menus etc are in widget area called Top bar and when i enter customize mode, the blue pencil sign doesnt show up for the 'divisions' unordered list menu

so i guess that area isnt a recognized widget area. maybe thats why it doesn't render as proper dropdown menu?

Comment: Please  add a working and relevant code snippet so we have something to work with. Don't expect us to dig trough your code. Also without code the question wouldn't make sense when your code changes

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution... you may be able to install a "Menu" plugin that will override the default one (if your theme does not support sub-menus) being used, and allow you to add and customise drop down menu's in your header.

Comment: will try that. ty